# Python:- Return None after an else statement and not using an else have different effects?

Tags: python, pygal

So I've been doing some work with python's pygal.maps.world module and had a question regarding Return none statements after an else and not using an else at all.

For example:

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES


def get_country_code(country_name):
  for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
    if name == country_name:
        return code
    else:
        return None


print(get_country_code('United Arab Emirates'))
```

This will print None, But if i do the following:

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES


def get_country_code(country_name):
  for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
    if name == country_name:
        return code

  return None


print(get_country_code('United Arab Emirates'))
```

Prints out the correct country code, could somebody explain why? Shouldn't the code act the same way regardless of an else statement or not?

Another thing I found was while running the first code block and attempting to get the country code of Andorra, I actually do manage to get the right country code, every other country doesn't work. What is going on here?

Edit:- Thanks for the answers, knew it was pretty obvious, should have thought about it a little more.

Comment: In the first code snippet, you return a `None` when you just see the first name does not match with `country_name`. In the second code, you'll iterate through all names until you see a name that matches with `country_name` or the loop is exhausted. So analysing your output, there is atleast one name that matches `country_name`.

Comment: Hey, great to see you working with Python. Dictionaries (which COUNTRIES variable is) can be accessed with `.get()` function. All you need to do is `print(COUNTRIES.get('United Arab Emirates'))`. Nothing else. This will by default return None if not found and will also speed things up as Dictionaries are meant to be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you check for each element if it's the correct name. But if it's not you immediately return out of the function, causing the for loop to not check the other items in the array.

In your second example you check if the element has the correct name, if it is you return the code. But if none of the elements match you return `None`. That's the difference.

Comment: Looking at [World map](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html) each country is only in there once and has one code. A dictionary means items have a `key` and a `value`. It doesn't mean it's a literal dictionary. see: [Python dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This loop is only run for one time with else condition. It checks just one name in items and If it is not matched with country_name it returns None.

```
def get_country_code(country_name):
  for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
    if name == country_name:
        return code
    else:
        return None #it returns in the first does not match condition
```

However the second loop is run till the end of items. Then it finds the country_name and return it

Answer (score 0):

Here in the below code your else block is inside the for loop so if it does not satisfy if condition it goes to else part and returns "None" and loop breaks

```
  for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
    if name == country_name:
        return code
    else:
        return None
```

But for below code it returns "code" if country is found and does not break till the last element of `COUNTRIES`

```
def get_country_code(country_name):
  for code, name in COUNTRIES.items():
    if name == country_name:
        return code

  return None
```